# Problems with Firestore Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some issues with Cloud Firestore. I have an activity where the user can upload a profile with text, an image view, and a progress bar, and then an activity that shows the profile. When I hit the button, the data never uploads, the progress bar just keeps running but I've noticed that the image is loaded in the Storage in Firebase but the "database" of the texts doesn't show. I've run the app on debug mode and it shows this:

```
" I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<

D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false

D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7e418b2000)

D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7e418b2000,api=1)

W/Firestore: (22.1.1) [WriteStream]: (412dab7) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

W/Firestore: (22.1.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at receta/profile: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e418b2000,api=1)

D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{ea950d4 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-257,86}

D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false

D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7e418b2000)

D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7e418b2000,api=1)

D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e418b2000,api=1)

D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{399fdc3 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-314,86} "
```

Here's my code:

```
    ImageView imageView;
    EditText et_titrec, et_ingre, et_rece;
    Button button;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    UploadTask uploadTask;
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference documentReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_receta);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview_agrerec);
        et_titrec = findViewById(R.id.et_titrec);
        et_ingre = findViewById(R.id.et_ingre);
        et_rece = findViewById(R.id.et_receta);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btn_agregarreceta);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar_ar);

        documentReference = db.collection("receta").document("profile");
        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profile image");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UploadData();
            }
        });
    }

    public void elegirImagen(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE || resultCode == RESULT_OK || data !=null || data.getData() !=null){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(imageView);
        }
    }

    private String getFileExt (Uri uri){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private void UploadData(){
        String titulo = et_titrec.getText().toString();
        String ingredientes = et_ingre.getText().toString();
        String receta = et_rece.getText().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(titulo) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(ingredientes) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(receta) || imageUri != null){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExt(imageUri));

            uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageUri);

            Task<Uri> uriTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return reference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<>();
                        profile.put("titulo", titulo);
                        profile.put("ingredientes", ingredientes);
                        profile.put("receta", receta);
                        profile.put("url", downloadUri.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(agregarReceta.this,"Receta cargada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        documentReference.set(profile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(agregarReceta.this,"Receta cargada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent i = new Intent(agregarReceta.this, mostrarReceta.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(agregarReceta.this, "Error al cargar receta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debes llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

*Here are the rules of Firestore*

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the relevant Firestore code as well as your related Firestore security rules?

Comment: @SammyT done! hope that's what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your security rules `allow read, write: if false;` are completely closing off access to the database.

The easiest way to resolve this while you're developing is to change your security to open access. These rules should be ok to use in development. But, you most likely wouldn't want to use open access rules in a production application:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

A better solution would be to include authentication in your application and limit access to your database only to authenticated users with these rules:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

You can find more info on security rules at the following links:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rules
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the firestore and now I'm working with Realtime Database and it worked xd now i'm trying to figure out how to show that data in a recyclerview. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, @MerlinaGutiérrez. If my answer solved your question, please remember to mark it as accepted.